# Unknown CMake command "add_rostest"

Tags: ros, tutorial, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorial on [overlaying on catkin workspaces](https://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) and run catkin as `$ catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3` but I get

```
CMake Warning at ros_tutorials/rospy_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:102 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findrostest.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "rostest", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rostest" with any
  of the following names:

    rostestConfig.cmake
    rostest-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rostest" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "rostest_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "rostest" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


CMake Error at ros_tutorials/rospy_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:112 (add_rostest):
  Unknown CMake command "add_rostest".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pra-dan/ros/overlay_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pra-dan/ros/overlay_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

What's wrong here ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364286/unknown-cmake-command-%22add_rostest%22./) by [pra-dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/58760/pra-dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-rostest
```

or replace noetic with whatever version you use.

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2020-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pra-dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/58760/pra-dan/) on 2020-10-28**:
It worked. Thanks